# jQuery Drop event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to move links (.link) from one div (.folder) to another but the drop event is not firing. I think I made all .link divs droppable areas by preventing default behaviour in dragenter and dragover events. Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Logic for create folder button
    $("#create-folder-button").click(createFolder);

    // //Logic for drag and drop for the links
    $(".folder").on("dragstart", function(e) {
        console.log("dragstart");
    });
    $(".folder").on("dragenter dragover", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $(".folder").on("drop", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("drop");
    });
});
```

The "dragstart" prints but the "drop" doesnt.

Comment: please a fiddle and also explain what you are expecting ?

Comment: Right now I would just like it to print the "drop". I have several divs with class "folder" and <a>s inside them. I would like to move them around the divs.

Comment: Is this code wrapped in a `$(document).ready(){ }`? If not, and this comes before _folder_ is defined, that could be the problem.

Comment: It is. The "dragstar" prints but the drop doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `event.stopPropagation()`:

```
$(".folder").on("drop", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert("Dropped!");
});
```

Comment: @JoaquimFerrer Little late! As the method suggests, it prevents the event from propagating the usual submission "chain" in DOM - say this button is in a form, `preventDefault` stops the button's default event from happening, and `stopPropagation` prevents the event from activating the form submission - together they handle the contextual `this` default event, and any side-effect events